# Enforce pylint score to merge on a github branch

Tags: python, git, github, pylint, software-quality

I would like to setup a quality check that enforces a certain score from pylint before authorizing a merge on a certain github branch. Is there a way to do this ? I see on github that you can set up "Require status checks to pass before merging" and I guess one status check could be a certain score on pylint.

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a solution for this: Use the new `--fail-under` flag.

> "If the final score is more than the specified score, it's considered
>   a success and pylint exits with exit code 0. Otherwise, it's
>   considered a failure and pylint exits with its current exit code based
>   on the messages issued."

https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/commit/16017690196e77fcabdedf1cd8b8cbfb357a97d4

Comment: I can't find this flag in `pylint` feature [list](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html) or in example [pylintrc](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/master/pylintrc), am I missing something?

Comment: The future is pretty new, it might not be documented yet?

Comment: Tested it, it does not work in the latest version either.